# The Cauchy product $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log n}{e^n}= \left( 1-\frac{1}{e} \right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log n!}{e^n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, special-functions, closed-form, cauchy-product

I know that the **Cauchy product** is defined 
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log n}{e^n}\right)\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{e^n} \right)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log k}{e^{k+n-k+1}},$$
and from this compute 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log n}{e^n}= \left( 1-\frac{1}{e} \right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log n!}{e^n}. $$

My purpose was to state a nice identity, but I have problems. My computations were by **partial summation** 
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\log n}{e^n}=[x]\frac{\log x}{e^x}-\int_1^x [t]\frac{\frac{1}{t}-\log t}{e^t}dt,$$
where the first summand in RHS vanishes as $x\to\infty$, and the integral converges. If there are no mistakes, I know write this last as the series of
$$k\int_k^{k+1}\frac{\frac{1}{t}-\log t}{e^t}dt.$$

But I don't know if it is possible continue, because **Wolfram Alpha** say that $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\log n}{e^n}$ is equal to $$-PolyLog^{(1,0)}(0,\frac{1}{e}).$$

I don't know if such exercise is in the literature, I ask it

> **Question.** Can you compute $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log n!}{e^n}$$ or explain what is $$-PolyLog^{(1,0)}(0,\frac{1}{e})$$ (I say a understandable explanation, how is defined this last special function, how to evaluate this particular value and why converges it) to get an identity? **Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polylogarithm function is defined as $$\textrm{Li}_{s}\left(z\right)=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{z^{k}}{k^{s}}
 $$ for all complex $s$ and for $\left|z\right|<1
 $. So observe that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\textrm{Li}_{s}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\right)=-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\log\left(k\right)}{e^{k}k^{s}}
 $$ and so $$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\textrm{Li}_{s}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\right)_{s=0}=-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\log\left(k\right)}{e^{k}}
 $$ and this is the $PolyLog^{\left(1,0\right)}\left(0,\frac{1}{e}\right)$ of Wolfram alpha. So the parenthesis $(1,0)$ indicates the differentiation with respect to $s$ one time and no differentiation with respect to $z$.

Comment: Now I understad this special function, I believe that the purpose of my question is satisfied, because I unerstand more better previous Cauchy product. Very thanks much for the lesson.